# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher

Tags: struts2

I'm new to Struts and I got issue like this

```
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 10, 2011 10:40:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.32
Mar 10, 2011 10:40:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4071)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Mar 10, 2011 10:40:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Mar 10, 2011 10:40:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/StrutsPrj] startup failed due to previous errors
Mar 10, 2011 10:40:39 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Mar 10, 2011 10:40:39 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Mar 10, 2011 10:40:39 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/16  config=null
Mar 10, 2011 10:40:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 625 ms
```

Also I got some probs in my struts.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>**
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"  "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="AppResources" />
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
        <action name="login"
            class="sturts2.LoginAction">
            <result name="success">Welcome.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">Login.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

In first line of struts.xml, I got error like this:

> Referenced file contains errors (http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd). For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..."

Comment: Once you have S2 set up correctly you don't even need a single jsp, just type in something.action and if you get a "Struts Problem Report" page which will also have "There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name something. - [unknown location]" on the page. So you can tell S2 is handling the requests.

Comment: We will need your to see your web.xml. Are you using maven for the build? Have you followed the instruction here to set up the project http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1.1/docs/how-to-create-a-struts-2-web-application.html ? Do you have all the jars listed under the ant build section in your class path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. Copy all the necessary jar files to WebContent > WEB-INF > lib folder
2. Make sure that you have added **commons-lang3-3.1** and **struts2-core-2.3.16.3**